# Phantomjs - page.content is not updated after a DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phantomjs

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open('http://xyz.ww', function() {
        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() { 
            var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
              $("span.disabled[name=comments]").click();
              return $(".content-right").html();
            });
           console.log(ua);    
           phantom.exit()

       });
    });
```

As you can see  I tried to click a span in the web page, which triggers an Ajax call and change the content of ".content-right" div. But when I write $(".content-right").html(), it returns again the initial content as if no Ajax call was made. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax takes some time but you're immediately checking if right column is updated. You should wait for comments to load after click.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://xyz.ww', function() {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() { 

        page.evaluate(function() {
          $("span.disabled[name=comments]").click();
        });

        // Let's wait 3 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
            var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
              $("span.disabled[name=comments]").click();
              return $(".content-right").html();
            });

            console.log(ua);    
            phantom.exit()

        }, 3000);

   });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing changed; I even set it to 10 seconds but still the initial content is returned.

Comment: Have you checked (with a screenshot) that comments are actually loaded? Could be that you click the wrong place.